# Adding assert function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and going through Learn Ruby the Hard Way right now. In the lesson I am supposed to add the Assert feature to Dict.rb (shown below). Would anyone know how I can go about doing this? Every time I try I receive an error.

```
module Dict

    #Creates a new function that makes a Dictionary. This is done through creating the 
    # aDict variable that has an array in which num_buckets array is placed inside.
    # These buckets will be used to hold the contents of the Dict and later aDict.length
    # is used to find out how many buckets there are.  
    def Dict.new(num_buckets=256)
        # Initializes a Dict with the given number of buckets.
        aDict = []
        (0...num_buckets).each do |i|
            aDict.push([])
        end

        return aDict
    end

    # Converts a string to a number using the bult-in Ruby 'hash' function
    # Once I have a number for the key, I use the % operator and aDict.length to get a 
    # bucket where the remainder can go. 
    def Dict.hash_key(aDict, key)
        # Given a key this will create a number and then convert it to an index for the
        # aDict's buckets
        return key.hash % aDict.length
    end

    # Uses hash_key to find a bucket that the key could be in. Using bucket_id I can get 
    # the bucket where the key could be. By using the modulus operator I know it will fit
    # into the aDict array of 256.
    def Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)
        # Given a key, find the bucket where it would go.
        bucket_id = Dict.hash_key(aDict, key)
        return aDict[bucket_id]
    end

    # Uses get_slot to get the (i, k, v) and returns the v (value) only. 
    def Dict.get_slot(aDict, key, default=nil)
        # Returns the index, key and value of a slot found in a bucket.
        bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)

        bucket.each_with_index do |kv, i|
         k, v = kv
         if key == k
            return i, k, v
         end
        end

        return -1, key, default
    end

    def Dict.get(aDict, key, default=nil)
        # Gets the value in a bucket for the given key or the default.
        i, k, v = Dict.get_slot(aDict, key, default=default)
        return v
    end

    # Sets a key/value pair by getting the bucket and appending the new (key, value) to it.
    # First you have to get the bucket, see if the key already exists, if it does then
    # replace it, if it doesn't get replaced then append it. 
    def Dict.set(aDict, key, value)
        # Sets the key to the value, replacing any existing value.
        bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)
        i, k, v = Dict.get_slot(aDict, key)

        if i >= 0
            bucket[i] = [key, value]
        else
            bucket.push([key, value])
        end
    end

    # Deletes a key by getting the bucket, searching for key in it and deleting it form the
    # array. 
    def Dict.delete(aDict, key)
        # Deletes the given key from the Dict.
        bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)

        (0...bucket.length).each do |i|
            k, v = bucket[i]
            if key == k
                bucket.delete_at(i)
                break
            end
        end
    end

    # goes through each slot in each bucket and prints out what's in the Dict. 
    def Dict.list(aDict)
        # Prints out what's in the Dict.
        aDict.each do |bucket|
            if bucket
                bucket.each {|k, v| puts k, v}
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I am using the following script to run methods from the module Dict.rb:

```
require './dict.rb'

# create a mapping of state to abbreviation
states = Dict.new()
Dict.set(states, 'Oregon', 'OR')
Dict.set(states, 'Florida', 'FL')
Dict.set(states, 'California', 'CA')
Dict.set(states, 'New York', 'NY')
Dict.set(states, 'Michigan', 'MI')

# create a basic set of states and some cities in them
cities = Dict.new()
Dict.set(cities, 'CA', 'San Francisco')
Dict.set(cities, 'MI', 'Detroit')
Dict.set(cities, 'FL', 'Jacksonville')

# add some more cities
Dict.set(cities, 'NY', 'New York')
Dict.set(cities, 'OR', 'Portland')

# puts out some cities
puts '-' * 10
puts "NY State has: #{Dict.get(cities, 'NY')}"
puts "OR State has: #{Dict.get(cities, 'OR')}"

# puts some states
puts '-' * 10
puts "Michigan's abbreviation is: #{Dict.get(states, 'Michigan')}"
puts "Florida's abbreviation is: #{Dict.get(states, 'Florida')}"

# do it by using the state then cities dict
puts '-' * 10
puts "Michigan has: #{Dict.get(cities, Dict.get(states, 'Michigan'))}"
puts "Florida has: #{Dict.get(cities, Dict.get(states, 'Florida'))}"

# puts every state abbreviation
puts '-' * 10
Dict.list(states)

# puts every city in state
puts '-' * 10
Dict.list(cities)

puts '-' * 10
# by default ruby says "nil" when something isn't in there
state = Dict.get(states, 'Texas')

if !state
    puts "Sorry, no Texas."
end

# default values using ||= with the nil result
city = Dict.get(cities, 'TX', 'Does Not Exist')
puts "The city for the state 'TX' is: #{city}"
```

Comment: Can you explain what this 'assert feature' is supposed to do? What errors are you getting?

Comment: From reading on [link](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html) I believe the assert feature is supposed to check if a particular test is true and if false print a particular statement. My confusion at the moment is how this assert feature actually fits into a script. The error I get is: ex39c.rb:48:in `<main>': undefined method `assert' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "assert" method by default in Ruby. That's why you are getting an "undefined method" error. You either need to implement this method yourself or use a testing framework like [Minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest) or [Rspec](http://rspec.info/).

If you want to implement a simple assert method yourself it would be something like this:

```
def assert(first_item, second_item)
  unless first_item == second_item
    puts "[Error] #{first_item} does not equal #{second_item}"
  end
end
```

And then use it like this:

```
assert(Dict.get(cities, 'NY'), 'New York')
```

The idea is that assertions help you make sure your code returns the expected output without having to check it manually.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work. Not everywhere yet, but I'll keep plugging your idea away.